# Importing postgres database in a docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to import an existing database into a postgres docker container.
This is how I proceed:

> docker run --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***** -d -p 5432:5432 -v BCS/postgres_data  postgres

Then

```
docker exec -it pg-docker bash
psql -U postgres
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE myDB;
psql -U postgres myDB < BCS/mydb.sql
```

but when i execute the command `\dt` I have this error `Did not find any relations.`

knowing that my database has already tables.
So waht I am doing wrong?

Comment: why not copying your sql file to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` ?

Comment: I add this instruction to my dockerFile, then how o verify if my database is well imported?

Answer (score 7):

First thing better to go with the approach that is mentioned by @LinPy.

Or better to copy at build time.

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres
COPY mydb.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Another option, you do need to script for only DB creation.

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```

The will create DB for you.

**POSTGRES_DB**

> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different
>   name for the default database that is created when the image is first
>   started. If it is not specified, then the value of POSTGRES_USER will
>   be used.

In the above, the [Postgres entrypoint](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) will take care of the SQL script.

Second thing, **the current issue with database name**, Postgress will not treat them in uppercase simply, unless you did some [trick](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

> Postgresql treats the db name as lowercase, normalising. However, the
>   field in the postgresapi does not replicate this behaviour, thus
>   allowing you to create a database with Capital letters. The fix could
>   be to warn the user that no uppercase letters are allowed in the db
>   aname and to add in a validation rule to the API to stop a user
>   creating such a database.

[postgres-api](https://github.com/tsuru/postgres-api/issues/8)

Change your command to
create DB

```
docker exec -it pg-docker bash
psql -U postgres
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE myDB;
```

verfiy DB

```
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 mydb      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
```

so the import command will be

```
psql -U postgres mydb < BCS/mydb.sql
```

or

```
psql  -d mydb -U postgres -f ab.sql
```

Comment: I add this instruction to my dockerFile, then how o verify if my database is well imported?

Comment: connect with any postgress client or you can cofirm from command like.

Answer (score 6):

You can also have your sql scripts being redirected to the container like that:

Postgres user:

```
docker exec -i my-postgres-container psql -U postgres < created-db.sql
```

Regular user:

```
docker exec -i my-postgres-container psql -d my-db -U my-user < create-schema.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the database installed everything correctly, are you are still not seeing tables, there are 2 things you should double-check:

- When you connect, are you connecting to the right database? If you are using `psql` in a terminal, the database is specified with the `-d` switch.

```
 psql -h <host> -U <user> -d <dbname>
```

You can also change your database after you connect using the `\connect <dbname>` command.

- Are you specifying the right schema? `\dt` will show you tables, but you need to specify a schema first using `set schema`:

```
postgres=# \dt

...
<no tables>
...

postgres=# set schema 'my_schema';
postgres=# \dt

...
<my tables>
...
```